# each() function skips in JQuery and does nothing on arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, each

I wrote this code to iterate of each element of Reshte array but it skips all and it's contents never runs

```
Reshte = $('.seeker_register select[name="Reshte[]"]').toArray();
Gerayesh = $('.seeker_register select[name="Gerayesh[]"]').toArray();
Moadel = $('.seeker_register select[name="Moadel[]"]').toArray();

// Reshte.each(function(index, el) {
 Reshte.each(function(index, el) {
    if ($(Reshte[index].val() )){
        review_page += 'Diplom: '+
        $(Reshte[index]).val()+ '   '+
        $(Gerayesh[index]).val()+ '  Moadel:'+
        $(Moadel[index]).val();
    };
});
```

Reshte array is not empty. This is it:

```
Reshte =
Array [ <select#Reshte.form-control>, <select#Reshte.form-control>, <select#Reshte.form-control>, <select#Reshte.form-control>, <select#Reshte.form-control> ]
```

Comment: try `$(this).va()` instead of  `Reshte[index].val()`

Comment: JS arrays don't have an `each()` method. They do have a `forEach()` method. Or jQuery objects have an `each()` method but `Reshte` is not a jQuery object. How about checking your browser's developer console for errors?

Comment: Arrays don't have `.each()` method but jQuery objects (returned by `$()`) do have `.each()`. So if you call `.toArray()` you cannot use `.each()` but if you don't call `.toArray()` you can use `.each()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need them as array they are already stored as such and jQuery give you a nice `each()` method to loop over them and an `eq()` method to access them by array index. `each()` doesn't exist on arrays it only works because it inherit jQuery's own each method.

Also you had a bug in your `if` condition `$(Reshte[index].val() )`. `Reshte[index]` would not have a `val()` as a native DOMElement. And even if it did this would take the value and pass it to `$()` when the element is what you want to pass and call `val()` on that.

```
Reshte = $('.seeker_register select[name="Reshte[]"]');
Gerayesh = $('.seeker_register select[name="Gerayesh[]"]');
Moadel = $('.seeker_register select[name="Moadel[]"]');

Reshte.each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).val()){ // bug fix here
        review_page += 'Diplom: '+
        $(this).val() + '   '+
        Gerayesh.eq(index).val() + '  Moadel:'+
        Moadel.eq(index).val();
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was a wrong parentes in if statement. As you said the array is not necessary but each() method works with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can use `for`

```
for (var i = 0; i < Reshte; i++) {
    //alert(Reshte[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

---

You can use Jquery method [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each(Reshte, function(index, el){
  // your code
});
```

In your code you are getting error if you use : `Reshte.each`

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `toArray()`, since `.each()` is a jQuery method, which should be called on a jQuery object. JS arrays are not jQuery objects.

So simply remove it and should be fine.